# ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to implement genetic algorithm, the program terminates after 1st generation.. not sure why.. the code is below.. the xeception raised is..

> File
>   "C:\Users\Eshan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\random.py",
>   line 255, in choice
>       i = self._randbelow(len(seq))   File "C:\Users\Eshan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\random.py",
>   line 232, in _randbelow
>       r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Eshan/Desktop/model/simple_ga.py", line 87, in 
>       ga()   File "C:/Users/Eshan/Desktop/model/simple_ga.py", line 32, in ga
>       agents = crossover(agents)   File "C:/Users/Eshan/Desktop/model/simple_ga.py", line 62, in crossover
>       parent1 = random.choice(agents)   File "C:\Users\Eshan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\random.py",
>   line 257, in choice
>       raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import random
import string


class Agent:
    def __init__(self, length):

        self.string = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(length))
        self.fitness = -1

    def __str__(self):
        return 'String: ' + str(self.string) + ' Fitness: ' + str(self.fitness)


in_str = 'string-python'
in_str_len = len(in_str)
population = 20
generations = 1000


def ga():

    agents = init_agents(population, in_str_len)

    for generation in range(generations):

        print('Generation: ' + str(generation))

        agents = selection(agents)
        agents = fitness(agents)
        agents = crossover(agents)
        agents = mutation(agents)

        if any(agent.fitness >= 90 for agent in agents):
            print('Threshod met!')
            exit(0)


def init_agents(population, length):
    return [Agent(length) for _ in range(population)]


def fitness(agents):
    for agent in agents:
        agent.fitness = fuzz.ratio(agent.string, in_str)

    return agents


def selection(agents):

    agents = sorted(agents, key=lambda agent: agent.fitness, reverse=True)
    print('\n'.join(map(str, agents)))
    agents = agents[:int(0.2 * len(agents))]
    return agents


def crossover(agents):
    offspring = []
    for _ in range(int((population - len(agents)) / 2)):
        parent1 = random.choice(agents)
        parent2 = random.choice(agents)
        child1 = Agent(in_str_len)
        child2 = Agent(in_str_len)
        split = random.randint(0, in_str_len)
        child1.string = parent1.string[0:split] + parent2.string[split:in_str_len]
        child2.string = parent2.string[0:split] + parent1.string[split:in_str_len]
        offspring.append(child1)
        offspring.append(child2)

    return agents


def mutation(agents):

    for agent in agents:
        for idx, param in enumerate(agent.string):
            if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) <= 0.1:
                agent.string = agent.string[0:idx] + random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + agent.string[idx+1:in_str_len]

    return agents

if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_str = 'string-python'
    in_str_len = len(in_str)
    ga()
```

Comment: Your "agent" field line 62 is empty. You can't perform a random.choice on an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `agents` is empty, so when you do `parent1 = random.choice(agents)`, this raises the error you're seeing, because you can't make a random choice from an empty list.

Comment: But why does agents get empty in between of the first generation?? The program does produce some outputs.. but not complete set of outputs..

Comment: Print the agents between the selection, fitness and crossover, it will be easy to pin down which function is making your list empty.

Comment: Personally, I'd check this line first: `agents = agents[:int(0.2 * len(agents))]`